# Google script Can't get SheetID to return value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get the following code, what am I missing?  Bottom line, I need to move or create the NEW spreadsheet in the folder.  But it seems I need an ID for that, which I can seem to pull.
Thanks!
Rudy

```
  var ss =SpreadsheetApp.create('Credit Card Issues with EZ-Pay')

  Logger.log('CREATING FILE.');
  //var folder = DocsList.getFolder("EZ-Pay Reports");
 //var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 Logger.log(ss.getSheetId('Sheet1'));
var ssID = ss.getSheetId('Sheet1');
  DocsList.getFileById(ssID).addToFolder(DocsList.getFolder("Credit Card Issues with EZ-Pay/EZ-Pay Reports"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code is much simpler :

```
function createInFolder(){
  var ss =SpreadsheetApp.create('Credit Card Issues with EZ-Pay')
  DocsList.getFileById(ss.getId()).addToFolder(DocsList.getFolder("Credit Card Issues with EZ-Pay/EZ-Pay Reports"));
  DocsList.getFileById(ss.getId()).removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());
}
```

Comment: Thank you Serge!  This worked.  One modification  is this line DocsList.getFileById(ss.getId()).addToFolder(DocsList.getFolder("EZ-Pay Reports")); When I ran the code, it was looking for a folder with the name "Credit Card Issues with EZ-Pay".  So I removed that section.Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The DocsList service has been deprecated. Use the [Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/) instead:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("Credit Card Issues with EZ-Pay");
var id = ss.getId();
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
DriveApp.addFile(file); // adds to the root folder
```

You can also add the file to a folder other than the root:

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderbyId(id);
folder.addFile(file);
```

If you don't know the id of the folder:

```
var folderIter = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("My Folder");
while (folderIter.hasNext()) { // returns true if the collection has a next item
  var folder = folderIter.next(); // throws an exception if there's no next item
}
folder.addFile(file);
```